# atom.io : Open Files via Clickable Links within Javascript Comments

Tags: javascript, node.js, ide, atom-editor

Is there way, in [Atom](https://atom.io/), to open files that are mentioned in comments?

When I edit a code file, there are often other code files of interest that I may want to also open while working on that file. Sometimes these reference files are miles away and require numerous steps of navigation to open them via the left-pane tree structure.

I was thinking, it would be nice if I could put relative file paths into javascript comments in a manner that atom would understand that if I click that path it should open that file in a new tab.

I suspect this isn't an original idea, so I'm hoping someone can direct me to a solution that enables this type of functionality or make me aware of how it is already enabled but I must use some syntax I'm not currently using.

Answer (score 0):

I found [open-project-file](https://atom.io/packages/open-project-file) and it seems like a nice fit.

**Update:** I tested it and it works great! You just click on the relative path (whether it is located in code **or comment**) and by hitting ctrl-shift-o it immediately opens the file in a new tab within the atom editor.